# strange logic to print numbers backwards

Tags: java, recursion

here is  the problem requirement

Write a method writeNums that accepts an integer parameter n and prints the first n integers starting with 1 in sequential order, separated by commas. For example, the following calls produce the following output:

Call    Output
writeNums(5);   1, 2, 3, 4, 5

And here is a solution (Partially it is my work and partially, I searched online). What I don;t understand is why this line writeNums(n - 1); printing the numbers backwards? It is a bit confusing because I was expecting to get this printed:
5,4,3,2,1

```
public class WriteNums
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
WriteNums wn=new WriteNums();
wn.writeNums(5);
}

public static void writeNums(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
      System.out.print("1");
    else {
      System.out.println(n);
      writeNums(n - 1);
      System.out.print(", " + n);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Look into recursion and also stack of recursive calls

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you step through the code?

Comment: if number is not 1,it again calls writeNum(n-1),but then why does system.out print in reverse order?

Comment: What would you say is the ratio of your code and online code? 50/50? 10/90? 1/99? First you copy your homework off the web, then you ask for us to explain it to you.

Comment: if you just want to print 1..5, this is not the way to do it.  This is an example of recursion.

Answer (score 2):

its because you are using recursion, and the output you printed is after the function call.

make it before function call and you will get 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

like this:

```
public static void writeNums(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
      System.out.print("1");
    else {
        System.out.print(n+", ");
      writeNums(n - 1);
      //System.out.print(", " + n);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks! i think your reply pretty much solved my confusion.I will be brushing on my recursion skills now

Comment: glad to help!, i know recursion can be confusing at times.

Answer (score 1):

Your program produces the following output:

```
5
4
3
2
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Why does it do that?

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comes from the `System.out.println(n);` line. You're calling `writeNums(5)`, which calls then `writeNums(4)`, which calls `writeNums(3)` etc. Each call prints `n` on a new line before making another recursive call.

This part: `, 2, 3, 4, 5` is printed by the line `System.out.print(", " + n);` after the recursive call completes. So `writeNums(2)` will print `, 2` after the call to `writeNums(1)` returns, `writeNums(3)` will print `, 3` after the call to `writeNums(2)` returns etc.

If you want the program to print `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` just remove the `System.out.println(n);` line.

Answer (score 0):

The program is printing the numbers backward because you are asking it to print the numbers backward. See that the first iteration in your recursive calls, you first print `n` and then start with `n-1`. If you want to print the numbers in the ascending order, change your method to something like following:

```
public static void writeNums(int m, int n) {
    if(n < 1) return;
    System.out.print(m);
    if(m == n) return;
    writeNums(m+1, n);
  }
```

And then from your main method, call the function as `writeNums(1, <n>);`

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are printing out backward because you call the same method before printing the number and it will run itself until meet "if (n == 0)" and in that case, it will finish itself and will be able to continue to execute next line 
"System.out.print(", " + n)". So, that way prints all sequence.

```
public static void writeNums(int n) {
     if (n == 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }    
    else if (n == 1) {
            System.out.print(n);
        } else {
            writeNums(n-1);
            System.out.print(", " + n);
        }
    }
```